# Image not found on Rails + Phaser

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, sprite, phaser-framework

I'm trying to complete this tutorial of phaser but I can't get the images to load. I started by adding the following code to one of my views:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, '', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update });

function preload() {

  game.load.image ('sky', 'assets/images/sky.png');
  game.load.image ('ground', 'assets/images/platform.png');
  game.load.image ('star', 'assets/images/star.png');
  game.load.spritesheet ('dude', 'assets/images/dude.png', 32, 48);
}

var platforms;

function create() {

  game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
  game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'sky');
  platforms = game.add.group();
  platforms.enableBody = true;
  var ground = platforms.create(0, game.world.height - 64, 'ground');
  ground.scale.setTo(2, 2);
  ground.body.immovable = true;
  var ledge = platforms.create(400, 400, 'ground');
  ledge.body.immovable = true;
  ledge = platforms.create(-150, 250, 'ground');
  ledge.body.immovable = true;
}
```

The game window appears but none of the images are being displayed. When I inspect the page, I can see the following error message:

**Phaser.Loader - image[sky]: error loading asset from URL assets/images/sky.png**

It appears for every image I tried to load. I already checked if the path is correct, and it is. Anyone have an idea of what is happening?

Comment: have you tried calling your assets using the asset_url helper?  i.e.  `game.load.image ('sky', "#{asset_url('sky.png')");`

Comment: How did you verify that the path is correct? Do the images display as 404 in your browser's Network tab in the console?

Comment: Failed to load resource: http://localhost:3000/chats/assets/images/dude.png the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).

I tried placing the image files inside the assets folder of the ruby project. There's another place where I should try?